# Ms word paste as reference not plain text

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference

I have a long list of reference that should be entered in MS word. something like this:

```
[1] Nudo, R. J., Milliken, G. W., and Jenkins, W. M. , “Use-dependent alterations of movement representations in primary motor cortex of adult squirrel monkeys,” The Journal of Neuroscience, vol. 16, no. 2, pp. 785–807, 1996.


[2] Taub, E., Uswatte, G., and Elbert, T. , “New treatments in neurorehabilitation founded on basic research,” Nature Reviews Neuroscience, vol. 3, no. 3, pp. 228–236, 2002.
```

It is really time consuming to enter all of the references (almost 300) in word by hand. I want to know if it's possible to paste as a reference (not as a plain text)?

Comment: What do you mean by paste as reference?

Comment: Hi @Máté Juhász , I want to past as a reference, something like [1] which when you click on it goes to  [1] Nudo, R. J., Milliken, G. W.,...

Comment: @Máté Juhász  Like insert citation

Comment: Citations /references are referring to specific text, you don't just "add many of them at the end of the document". It's still difficult to understand what exactly you need.